# Laravel 5.8 model casts

Tags: php, model, laravel-5.8

Набрёл на странное (для меня) поведения модели в Laravel: при изменении атрибутов с помощью метода модели fill($data), преобразования по свойству $casts напрочь игнорируются.

```php
class User extends Model
{
   protected $casts = [
      'value' => 'integer',
   ];
}

$user = User::find(1);
$user->fill(['value'=> '1']);
is_int($user->value);   // false
```

Но если идёт присвоение через обращение напрямую, то всё работает.

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$user->value = '1';
is_int($user->value);   // true;
```

Как костыль можно использовать

```php
    public function setValueAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['value'] =  filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    }
```

Но это костыль... Или может я делаю что-то не так?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю в первом случае, вы пытаетесь через fill добавить данные в несуществующее св-во класса. Во втором случае вы объявляете св-во явно. Т.о. через маг. метод он у вас создаётся и заполняется. В 3-ем случае, всё тоже самое что и во втором. Явное объявление св-ва value.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы заполняете (изменяете) свойства объекта модели через create() или fill(), то необходимо добавлять в модель `protected $fillable = ['value']`. То есть, получается `mass assignable` как в документации, так как присваиваете массив на вход функции `fill`, а значит должно быть указано данное свойство. Проверяется `guarded` и не вызывается `$casts`. Предположу что такое поведение по этой причине.